# Complex table using WPF with merging headers

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

It should look like this table:

[image: table image]

The reason that I asking for your help is that I tried to find how to merge headers, but the answers are not very useful for me:

1. I used grid to add header, and then bind position of labels in order to columns widths 
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366/. BUT when I tried to horizontal scrolling (i have a lot of columns, as you can see) my "superheaders" were still on the same positions. Then I tried to make same task, but put `superheader` with `datagrid` in `ScrollView`. Result was good, but
2. If I add some groups to row headers and need to have vertical scrollbar - my `column header` with `superheader` would not be visible enough.
3. Using `DataGridTemplateColumn` isn't a good idea for me too. That`s because I need my cells to be "selectable", but when I use this kind of column all my subcolumns are selected together.

So my question is: How to make such kind of tables, or can anybody give me a link to free table tool that allows to make merging header easier.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `LayoutUpdated` event, that change row headers position in order to vertical scroll of datagrid

Comment: Moreover, diagram that i'm looking for called "gantt chart"